GSAP SplitType Text Line Breaks
I'm using GSAP SplitType to animate text in my portfolio, but I'm encountering an issue where the text breaks onto new lines, displaying incorrectly. I've attached some screenshots to illustrate:

The text in VS Code (to show it as one continuous sentence with no breaks, as intended): (https://i.sstatic.net/lt4YRy9F.png)
The HTML/data structure in the inspector during a live preview:(https://i.sstatic.net/AJJyU968.png)
How the text is rendered on the page (which is not how I want it):(https://i.sstatic.net/65JQ5lEB.png)

The JS code I'm using:
  const myText = new SplitType('#my-text')
  gsap.to('.char', {
      y: 0,
      stagger: 0.05,
      delay: 0.2,
      duration: .1
  })

The CSS used:
h1{
    font-size: clamp(2.5rem, 5vw + 1rem, 4.5rem);
    color: #333; max-width: 90%;
    clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
    line-height: 5rem;
}
.char {
    transform: translateY(350px);
    transition: transform .4s;
}

And here's the HTML:
<h1 id="my-text">Hi, I'm Ethan, a passionate UX/UI designer from the scenic landscapes of Northern Ireland.</h1>

Does anyone know how to prevent the text from breaking onto new lines and ensure it displays as one continuous sentence?
Thanks!

Could you show CSS? And also paste the code here so everyone can check and debug it.

@ŁukaszD.Mastalerz Sure! Here's the CSS:
h1{
font-size: clamp(2.5rem, 5vw + 1rem, 4.5rem);
color: #333;
max-width: 90%;
clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%);
line-height: 5rem;
}
.char {
transform: translateY(350px);
transition: transform .4s;
}
And here's the HTML:
Hi, I'm Ethan, a passionate UX/UI designer from the scenic landscapes of Northern Ireland.